# Can I repeat the subject in a sentence?

Tags: subjects, personal-pronouns

I have the following excerpt in a paragraph

> Professionals in the pain management field believe PE influences physiological mechanisms and outcomes of pain. **They** consider **they** should use PIs to examine the efficacy of any pain treatment.

Is it correct to repeat the subject (in bold) in the second part? Why?

Comment: It's not grammatically wrong, but the two 'theys' so close together doesn't sound very good.  I'd advise _They consider that they should..._ or, better still, _They consider that PIs should be used..._

Comment: The repeat is standard English: "I believe I can fly", "She thinks she has a cold" etc. But "consider" is not quite the right word. "They _believe/say/think_ they should use PIs..."might be better. Or as Kate Bunting suggests.

Comment: It's correct, but it's unclear, so avoid it if you can. You could rewrite the second sentence to be more clear this way: "They recommend using PIs to examine the efficacy of any new pain treatment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar is fine with both "they"s, but English style strongly prefers avoiding repetition.

I'd use the passive voice to remove the need for the second "they":

> "They consider ***PIs should be used*** to examine the efficacy of any pain treatment."

This has the added advantage of moving the more important PIs into subject position in favour of the less important "professionals".